# wkhtmltopdf call from PHP exec results in exit code 127 failure

Tags: php, centos, permissions, exec, wkhtmltopdf

Using CentOS 6.3x64.

I'm trying to run `wkhtmltopdf` (from [here](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2&can=2&q=)) from a PHP script.  I can successfully call `wkhtmltopdf-amd64` directly via SSH. But when calling it from PHP via `exec`, it always fails with exit code 127.  The path is correct, so that isn't the issue.  I can successfully use `exec` to call `ls` and `id` etc, so the problem seems to be specific to calling `wkhtmltopdf-amd64`.

I would presume this somehow relates to permissions, but I'm not sure what steps to take.  I've tried `apache:apache` and other ownerships on the program and it has 755 permissions.

Thanks for any guidance!

***Additional note:***

Sorry for not clarifying further above -- I have confirmed the issue does not relate to the path to the program.  I'm using the full absolute path.  I've confirmed that the exact same command can be run from the SSH line without problem (regardless of the `pwd`).  I've also created a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'hello, world!'
```

I can call this script via `exec` and it works properly.  However, if I modify it to be

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'hello, world!'
/full/path/to/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 'http://www.google.com/' /full/path/to/output.pdf
```

it then fails and returns the exit code 127.

Answer (score 2):

Your shell seems to be unable to find the binary. Try calling it with its full path name (e.g. `/usr/bin/ls` instead of `ls`). For further information, see [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: thanks for the advice; unfortunately, the path isn't the issue (see additional clarification added to the question).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back. In my case I got 126 without the execution bit set and 127 with the bit set.

I later figured out it was related to some shared libraries missing on the system. Even if the binary is linked statically it seems to use some shared libraries from the system.

I don't really remember which libraries were causing the problem, but this gist: https://gist.github.com/nghuuphuoc/8282411 is a good starting point I think.